# Use of “as” before adverb

Tags: prepositions

> I marked my age as above 40 .

While answering a questionnaire I ansewered a question which asked the age range  in the way above .Is use of “as” correct in sentence. What kind of grammer is use of as in this sentence , if it is wrong what should I say as an alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine to me.

*Above 40* is a non-specific numerical expression, syntactically equivalent to *forty*, *lots*, *a very small number* and other expressions with different internal structures.